# Regular sequence, and projective dimension

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $I\subset J$ be two ideals of  $k[x_{1},..,x_{n}]$, where $I$ is generated by a regular sequence.
What can we say about the projective dimension of $J/I$
Thank you!

Comment: By the Auslander-Buchsbaum Formula, the projective dimension of $J/I$ as a module over $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ equals $n$ minus the depth of $J/I$ as an $R/I$-module.  Unfortunately, you have not specified enough information to say much about the depth.  For instance, if $J/I$ is Artinian, so that the depth equals $0$, then the projective dimension of $J/I$ is maximal, equal to $n$.  However, if $J$ equals $R$, then the projective dimension equals the height of $I$.

Comment: But $R$ is not local ring?

Comment: The projective dimension of a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ is the maximum of the projective dimensions of the  $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$-modules $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$.  So you can reduce to the local case.  However, I do realize I missed one (possibly useful) observation.  Since $J/I$ is a submodule of $R/I$, and this module has depth equal to $n$ minus the height of $I$, the depth of $J/I$ is at least $1$ if $I$ is not primary for a maximal ideal (assuming $J\neq I$).  Thus, except if $I$ is primary for a maximal ideal, the maximal projective dimension of $J/I$ equals $n$, not $n-1$.

Comment: Yes by localisation!!

Comment: Can we for example have $pd J/I$ = $pd J$ under some conditions?

Comment: Or if $J$ is a prime ideal!

Comment: So for example if $I$ is generated by a maximal regular sequence of $J$, then $pd J/I$ = $n$.

Comment: The depth of $J/I$ as an $R/I-$module is the grade of the ideal $J/I$??